# ScrollView not scroll Android 5.0.2

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I have this xml file, but my scrollview not work:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:fancy="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
               tools:context="it.baywaylabs.duelautomazione.InsertRapportinoActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_insert_rapportino"
    android:scrollIndicators="right"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/Rapp1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Data:"
        android:id="@+id/days_text"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/data"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="210dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/data"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.23"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="170dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="27dp"
            android:layout_height="27dp"
            android:id="@+id/calendarRapportinoButton"
            android:src="@drawable/calendar"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|bottom" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Rapp1"
        android:id="@+id/Rapp2">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cliente:"
        android:id="@+id/cliente_text"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_below="@+id/days_text"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/cliente_spinner"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_below="@+id/data"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/data"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/data"
        android:layout_marginLeft="215dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Rapp2"
        android:id="@+id/Rapp3">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Commessa:"
        android:id="@+id/commesse_text"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cliente_text"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/commesse_spinner"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cliente_spinner"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cliente_spinner"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/cliente_spinner"
        android:layout_marginLeft="184dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Rapp3"
        android:id="@+id/Rapp4">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Responsabile:"
        android:id="@+id/responsabile_text"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_below="@+id/commesse_text"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/responsabile_spinner"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_below="@+id/commesse_spinner"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/commesse_spinner"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/commesse_spinner"
        android:layout_marginLeft="169dp" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Descrizione Attività:"
        android:id="@+id/commessa_description"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Rapp4"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/descriptionRapportino"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="2"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:maxLength="300"
        android:layout_below="@+id/commessa_description"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Rapp1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Rapp1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />


    <View android:layout_height="1px"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="#90909090"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/descriptionRapportino"
        android:id="@+id/separator1" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="570dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/separator1"
        android:id="@+id/tabelleScroll">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabelle"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Operatori:"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/operatoriText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/separator1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

        <de.codecrafters.tableview.TableView
            xmlns:table="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/tableOperatori"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            table:tableView_columnCount="2"
            table:tableView_headerColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Materiali:"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/materialiText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/days_spinner"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

        <de.codecrafters.tableview.TableView
            xmlns:table="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/tableMateriali"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            table:tableView_columnCount="2"
            table:tableView_headerColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Bolle:"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/bolleText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/days_spinner"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

        <de.codecrafters.tableview.TableView
            xmlns:table="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/tableBolle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            table:tableView_columnCount="3"
            table:tableView_headerColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />



    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabelleScroll"
        android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center|center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp">

        <mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton
            android:id="@+id/nuovaOra"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="250dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nuovaBolla"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            fancy:fb_ghost="true"
            fancy:fb_focusColor="#bfbebe"
            fancy:fb_fontIconSize="15sp"
            fancy:fb_radius="40dp"
            fancy:fb_iconPosition="right"
            fancy:fb_borderWidth="2dp"
            fancy:fb_borderColor="#ffe7e6e2"
            fancy:fb_text="Inserisci Operatore"
            fancy:fb_textSize="18sp"
            fancy:fb_textColor="#616060"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp" />

        <mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton
        android:id="@+id/nuovoArticolo"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:gravity="left"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="250dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nuovoRapportino"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        fancy:fb_ghost="true"
        fancy:fb_focusColor="#bfbfbe"
        fancy:fb_fontIconSize="15sp"
        fancy:fb_radius="40dp"
        fancy:fb_iconPosition="right"
        fancy:fb_borderWidth="2dp"
        fancy:fb_borderColor="#ffe7e6e2"
        fancy:fb_text="Inserisci Materiale"
            fancy:fb_textSize="18sp"
        fancy:fb_textColor="#616060"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp" />

    <mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton
        android:id="@+id/nuovaBolla"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="250dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nuovoArticolo"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        fancy:fb_ghost="true"
        fancy:fb_focusColor="#bfbfbe"
        fancy:fb_fontIconSize="15sp"
        fancy:fb_radius="40dp"
        fancy:fb_iconPosition="right"
        fancy:fb_borderWidth="2dp"
        fancy:fb_borderColor="#ffe7e6e2"
        fancy:fb_text="Inserisci Bolla"
        fancy:fb_textSize="18sp"
        fancy:fb_textColor="#616060"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="top">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Totale Rapportino: "
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nuovoArticolo"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="25dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/totaleRapportino"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton
            android:id="@+id/confermaRapportino"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            fancy:fb_ghost="true"
            fancy:fb_focusColor="#bfbfbe"
            fancy:fb_fontIconSize="15sp"
            fancy:fb_radius="40dp"
            fancy:fb_iconPosition="right"
            fancy:fb_borderWidth="2dp"
            fancy:fb_borderColor="#ffe7e6e2"
            fancy:fb_text="Conferma"
            fancy:fb_textSize="18sp"
            fancy:fb_textColor="#616060"
            android:layout_marginLeft="320dp" />

        <mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton
            android:id="@+id/firmaRapportino"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left|right"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            fancy:fb_ghost="true"
            fancy:fb_focusColor="#bfbfbe"
            fancy:fb_fontIconSize="15sp"
            fancy:fb_radius="40dp"
            fancy:fb_iconPosition="right"
            fancy:fb_borderWidth="2dp"
            fancy:fb_borderColor="#ffe7e6e2"
            fancy:fb_text="Firma"
            fancy:fb_textSize="18sp"
            fancy:fb_textColor="#616060"
            android:layout_marginLeft="320dp"
            android:gravity="right" />

    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried different ways and I read several questions but nothing, any suggestions? mMy ScrollView should be at the center of my view and contain 3 tables, they are updated by an adapter and when their length grows I wish ScrollView could contain them without moving other elements
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not very familiar with android, but you might mention some of what you tried to help narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

only copi and past the code in your xml fille

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:fancy="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
               tools:context="it.baywaylabs.duelautomazione.InsertRapportinoActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_insert_rapportino"
    android:scrollIndicators="right"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
 <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewDados"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchViewLista"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/Rapp1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Data:"
        android:id="@+id/days_text"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/data"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="210dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/data"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.23"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="170dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="27dp"
            android:layout_height="27dp"
            android:id="@+id/calendarRapportinoButton"
            android:src="@drawable/calendar"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|bottom" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Rapp1"
        android:id="@+id/Rapp2">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cliente:"
        android:id="@+id/cliente_text"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_below="@+id/days_text"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/cliente_spinner"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_below="@+id/data"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/data"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/data"
        android:layout_marginLeft="215dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Rapp2"
        android:id="@+id/Rapp3">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Commessa:"
        android:id="@+id/commesse_text"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cliente_text"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/commesse_spinner"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cliente_spinner"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cliente_spinner"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/cliente_spinner"
        android:layout_marginLeft="184dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Rapp3"
        android:id="@+id/Rapp4">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Responsabile:"
        android:id="@+id/responsabile_text"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_below="@+id/commesse_text"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/responsabile_spinner"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_below="@+id/commesse_spinner"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/commesse_spinner"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/commesse_spinner"
        android:layout_marginLeft="169dp" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Descrizione Attività:"
        android:id="@+id/commessa_description"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Rapp4"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/descriptionRapportino"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="2"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:maxLength="300"
        android:layout_below="@+id/commessa_description"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Rapp1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Rapp1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />


    <View android:layout_height="1px"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="#90909090"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/descriptionRapportino"
        android:id="@+id/separator1" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="570dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/separator1"
        android:id="@+id/tabelleScroll">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabelle"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Operatori:"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/operatoriText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/separator1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

        <de.codecrafters.tableview.TableView
            xmlns:table="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/tableOperatori"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            table:tableView_columnCount="2"
            table:tableView_headerColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Materiali:"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/materialiText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/days_spinner"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

        <de.codecrafters.tableview.TableView
            xmlns:table="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/tableMateriali"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            table:tableView_columnCount="2"
            table:tableView_headerColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Bolle:"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/bolleText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/days_spinner"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

        <de.codecrafters.tableview.TableView
            xmlns:table="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/tableBolle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            table:tableView_columnCount="3"
            table:tableView_headerColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />



    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabelleScroll"
        android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center|center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp">

        <mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton
            android:id="@+id/nuovaOra"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="250dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nuovaBolla"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            fancy:fb_ghost="true"
            fancy:fb_focusColor="#bfbebe"
            fancy:fb_fontIconSize="15sp"
            fancy:fb_radius="40dp"
            fancy:fb_iconPosition="right"
            fancy:fb_borderWidth="2dp"
            fancy:fb_borderColor="#ffe7e6e2"
            fancy:fb_text="Inserisci Operatore"
            fancy:fb_textSize="18sp"
            fancy:fb_textColor="#616060"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp" />

        <mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton
        android:id="@+id/nuovoArticolo"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:gravity="left"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="250dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nuovoRapportino"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        fancy:fb_ghost="true"
        fancy:fb_focusColor="#bfbfbe"
        fancy:fb_fontIconSize="15sp"
        fancy:fb_radius="40dp"
        fancy:fb_iconPosition="right"
        fancy:fb_borderWidth="2dp"
        fancy:fb_borderColor="#ffe7e6e2"
        fancy:fb_text="Inserisci Materiale"
            fancy:fb_textSize="18sp"
        fancy:fb_textColor="#616060"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp" />

    <mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton
        android:id="@+id/nuovaBolla"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="250dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nuovoArticolo"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        fancy:fb_ghost="true"
        fancy:fb_focusColor="#bfbfbe"
        fancy:fb_fontIconSize="15sp"
        fancy:fb_radius="40dp"
        fancy:fb_iconPosition="right"
        fancy:fb_borderWidth="2dp"
        fancy:fb_borderColor="#ffe7e6e2"
        fancy:fb_text="Inserisci Bolla"
        fancy:fb_textSize="18sp"
        fancy:fb_textColor="#616060"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="top">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Totale Rapportino: "
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nuovoArticolo"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="25dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/totaleRapportino"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton
            android:id="@+id/confermaRapportino"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            fancy:fb_ghost="true"
            fancy:fb_focusColor="#bfbfbe"
            fancy:fb_fontIconSize="15sp"
            fancy:fb_radius="40dp"
            fancy:fb_iconPosition="right"
            fancy:fb_borderWidth="2dp"
            fancy:fb_borderColor="#ffe7e6e2"
            fancy:fb_text="Conferma"
            fancy:fb_textSize="18sp"
            fancy:fb_textColor="#616060"
            android:layout_marginLeft="320dp" />

        <mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton
            android:id="@+id/firmaRapportino"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left|right"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            fancy:fb_ghost="true"
            fancy:fb_focusColor="#bfbfbe"
            fancy:fb_fontIconSize="15sp"
            fancy:fb_radius="40dp"
            fancy:fb_iconPosition="right"
            fancy:fb_borderWidth="2dp"
            fancy:fb_borderColor="#ffe7e6e2"
            fancy:fb_text="Firma"
            fancy:fb_textSize="18sp"
            fancy:fb_textColor="#616060"
            android:layout_marginLeft="320dp"
            android:gravity="right" />

    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Not work! Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child